# SQL - Is it possible to collapse or merge duplicate cells into a single cell once?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I've been looking for question such as this and found none.

My question is, is it even possible to hide other duplicate cell values and display only one of that unique value in a joined table? See tables below for clarification.

```
Table 1                   Table 2
ID    Gender              ID    NAME
1     Male                1     John
2     Female              2     Ann
3     Gay                 3     George
4     Gay                 4     James
5     Gay                 5     Justin
6     Bisexual            6     Floyd

Results table

Result 1                    Result 2

GENDER    NAME              GENDER    NAME
Male      John              Male      John
Female    Ann               Female    Ann
Gay       George            Gay       George
Gay       James                       James
Gay       Justin                      Justin
Bisexual  Floyd             Bisexual  Floyd
```

Now, in the tables above we all know that George, James and Justin are of the same gender. In a normal JOIN query the result table on the right will be displayed, but what I need is something of what the left result table is showing. Notice the 4th and fifth row column 1 in the right result table have empty values.

By the way, I need this for my application written in C# with MS Access database through OleDb using DataGridView, if there is a trick to solve this problem that is only available in other RDBMS except MS Access or a C# DataGridView workaround please let me also know.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little odd to be handling this kind of requirement in a database query - better to deal with it only for display at the UI or application layer.  Rows in a query are generally/easier to be thought of as independent from each other and with no particular order.

I don't know about MS Access's capabilities but in MS SQL databases you can use something like `SELECT ... ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY _?_) AS IndexByGender` which will give everyone except for James and Justin an `IndexByGender` of `1` and then you could do more computation either in the SQL Query or in the application to display the Gender *only* when `IndexByGender` equals `1`.

And, umm, I kept with your terminology for clarity, but your sample data is mixing concepts of "GenderIdentity" (or perhaps "AnatomicalGender") and "SexualOrientation" - so if this is your real domain, splitting them up might be a more useful design.  Just sayin'.

Comment: Ok, but do you have any idea of managing this in the UI part? I'm guessing that I should handle the DataGridView events, RIght? If that so then would that be inefficient?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly to handle this in the datagridview because I don't work with them much anymore, but if you want to deal with it in the data level then you probably need to iterate over the data at some point and either clear out the values that are repeated or create a new column that is the Index indicator (or the IsFirstOfGroup indicator)

Answer (score 0):

This type of result can be generated in any SQL dialect. From your initial relation perform the desired `Order By` and compute a rownumber for each row. Now self-left-outer-join the relation to itself on `lhs.rownumber = rhs.rownumber - 1` and only output your desired `GENDER` column from the lhs (ie as `lhs.GENDER`)  when `coalesce(rhs.GENDER,' ') <> lhs.GENDER`.

In some SQL dialects it may be necessary to store your relation in a temporary table in order to generate the rownumber values. Don't be afraid to do that if necessary. This self-left-outer-join technique is widely applicable when you need to create a windowing relationship between successive rows of a relation.